# which techonology is good for my online store?

Tags: web-applications

I am thinking about build a online store for my wife to sale something. we need database for customer info and goods info. we also need shopping cart for customers to use. I have yrs java experience but no web experience (know a little about jsp and servlet). I am thinking using wicket and other java technologies plus MySQL to build it. but I am open to other options. I am willing to learn new things.

what's your expert views? 
thanks,

Comment: How about becoming a seller on eBay. They've already written the platform.

Comment: that's one approach but we still want to have a separated location to sell.

Comment: go look into it. You can create custom stores with a custom appearance.

Comment: There are so many open source carts to choose from i'm not sure why anyone would want to build one from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in off-the-shelf solutions you can tinker with, you may want to look in the direction of [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/), [Spree](http://spreecommerce.com/) or if you want to avoid getting your hands dirty with coding at all** try [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/).

** Well, sounds like you do want to get your hands dirty ;)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd look at systems that are already out there, such as Magento or OSCommerce. Why reinvent the wheel, especially with all the cool features that already exist? Plus, doing online stores, the number one priority is security. Most likely the systems that are being used by thousands of stores will have better security than one you create yourself, no matter how experienced you are, as there's thousands of people looking and finding the holes.

Comment: you are right don't invent the wheel but Magento is "Starts at $11,125 USD/yr"

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA Magento is open source and freely available (http://www.magentocommerce.com/download). Perhaps you're looking at the Enterprise version with service agreement?

Answer (score 0):

[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) appears to be targeted at exactly your problem, especially in their "free to learn and test, and buy capacity as needed" approach.